# Public Static Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, static, public

I am just wondering if it is possible to have a public static array that can be accessed and edited by all classes.

To see if it works I have tried to access it but I just get an error.

```
public class FileManager {
    public static String[][] cassetteArray = new String[10][6];
}
```

The command I use to check if it works is;

```
FileManager.cassetteArray[0][1].length();
```

Instead I get the following error;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at AssignmentStage1.UserInterface.userMenu(UserInterface.java:35)
```

Comment: It does work. But you probably don't fill the array with values, so the array elements are all ``null``. And calling ``length()`` on a ``null`` reference...

Comment: You haven't put any `String`s into the elements of `FileManager.cassetteArray` in any of the code you've shown, nor, apparently in any other code you haven't shown either.

Comment: Ohh Ok! Thanks! I will try and give it some values. My question is answered though.

Answer (score 1):

This object has a null value `FileManager.cassetteArray[0][1]` so that's the reason of exception. 
However you can use singleton for that purpose.